# Minimum set cover problem and dual, the maximum set packing

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-programming

Just like in [This thread](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56923/maximum-set-packing-and-minimum-set-cover-duality) that was posted here before, I came upon the same issue where I do not understand how are the relaxed maximum set packing problem and the minimum set cover problem are dual to each other.

More precisely, how and why the optimal solution to the primal and dual LP problems should have the same value. Even after I know that the strong duality theorem applies only to the fractional LP of those problems - Which basically means I can take a fraction of each set $S_{i}$ or a fraction of each $u\in U$.

But how does it make sense? Even by the example given in the thread I linked, Let's say we consider a Universe $U$ and a collection of subsets of $U$ which is $S$:
$U=\{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$
$S=\{\{1,2,3 \}, \{3,4,5 \}, \{1 \}, \{2 \},\{3 \} \}$
Clearly the minimum set cover for this is 2, and yet considering the fractional case, the maximum set packing for this example clearly must be higher than 2.

And I can take fractions of both every $u\in U$ and every $S_{i}$, clearly the solution for the fractional minimum set cover and maximum set packing is not the same solution...
What am I missing here? It seems to me that the optimal solution to both problems must be different. I would love an example or an explanation of what I misunderstand.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make it self-contained. "I do not understand how are those problems dual to each other" - I don't know what "those problems" refers to.  Please articulate a specific question.  "What am I missing here?" and "But how does it make sense?" is a bit vague.  Can you formulate a more specific question?

Comment: @D.W. done, thank you!